# How do I prevent more than 2 numbers after a decimal point in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, decimal

Right Now I am making an app where the user is required to input a currency value, decimal point optional, into a UITextField. My problem comes up when I try to prevent more than 2 numbers after a given decimal point while at the same time preventing more than one decimal point. I have researched around the web and couldn't find an *exact* answer. I have found that I will most probably need to use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange, but I'm not sure how to use it exactly...

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a number formatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"###0.##"];
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@122344.4563];
NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", formattedNumberString);
// Output for locale en_US: "formattedNumberString: formattedNumberString: 122,344.45"
```

from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1

You would put this in one of your UITextFieldDelegate methods like `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. Get the most recent string by doing: `NSString *s = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];` Then you would get the number value of that string with `@([s floatValue])`, and then use the number formatter like shown above, then put it in the text field.

I would do some checking to make sure they have entered in at least two digits after the decimal before messing with their input. But this would be the correct, localized way to do it.

Comment: Which method would I use this in? I'm not really used to using NSNumberFormatter...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! helped a lot for something that isn't readably available on the internet ;)

Comment: Hi, I have one more question! How would I check if they put in at least to numbers after the decimal and what would I return for the method?

Answer (score 0):

```
// add a notification & use following function:

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textIsChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)textIsChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     NSString * currentText =  yourTextField.text;
 if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [currentText componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        if(arr.count == 2)
        {
            NSString *afterDecimalPart = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
            if(afterDecimalPart.length > 2)
            {
                currentText = [currentText substringToIndex:currentText.length-1];
                yourTextField.text = currentText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```